# google speech recognition weak date transcription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am using currently google asr/tts with german speech model (de-DE) and experience wrong results in certain usage scenarios of **date** extractions.

I am really keen on to know whether others might have similar results.

Let me give you some examples:

I am saying:

"der 1.10.1905" -> "1. 10195 11095"

"9.5.78" -> 90587

"22.11.98" -> 22.11 89

**BUT:**

"22. November 98" -> "22 November 98"

When I fully qualify the month word it works all fine.

I also checked the proposed way to optimize by using hints, without any improvement

```
"speechContexts": [
            {
              "phrases": [
                "$FULLDATE"
              ]
            }
          ]
```

Is this something one has to accept or is there anything that I can try on top?

Cheers Andre

**UPDATE:**
According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186559805 **the problem should be fixed**.

**But**
I could **not verify** it, maybe somebody else can ??!

I tried it with the following configuration, but it did not improve at all. Maybe overlooked something ?!

Here is my configuration. I performed the request with the beta client:

```
const {SpeechClient} = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1;


const googleRequest = {
  config: {
    encoding: "MULAW",
    sampleRateHertz: 8000,
    model: "command_and_search",
    languageCode: "de-DE",
    speechContexts: [
      {
        "phrases": [
          "$OOV_CLASS_FULLDATE"
        ]
      }
    ]

  },
  singleUtterance: true,
  interimResults: true
};
```

I also raised a new ticket to google developers.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243294056

Comment: Could you share a sample audio? As I don't know German, I am not sure I have a correct one. For example, for 9 do you use neun or neunte?

Comment: @Ksign, thanks supporting me. Yes, sure I could deliver an example, but to answer your question first. In german language one use: zwei und zwanzigster neunter neunzehn hundert acht und neunzig -> 22.9.1998. You put postfixes like you do in english as well: nine(th)

Comment: @Ksign, I have an wav example if you like ..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same results as you have when using your example. But it does transcribe correctly if the speaker says `ein tausend neun hundert acht und neunzig` instead.

It seems that, for some reason, in German, the API doesn't recognize when the speaker uses hundreds to express thousands (I.E. `nineteen hundred ninety eight` instead of `one thousand nine hundred ninety eight`).

I don't know German and can't confirm if this way of speaking numbers/dates is official but if you are sure that in German, it is officially accepted, then I suggest that you create an issue on [issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187181&template=1161156) with some references to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks @Ksign, I really appreciate that you put efforts into my problem:-) Although I have some other observation, as the 'year' does not produce a problem. You can say either way, but it makes a difference if you say 22. elfter 1998 oder 22. November 1998 - the latter works the other not. I will raise an issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried with **elfter** (`zwei und zwanzigster elfter ein tausend neun hundert acht und neunzig`) and **November** (`zwei und zwanzigster November ein tausend neun hundert acht und neunzig`) and I get a correct transcription for both. I didn't use the $FULLDATE speechContext token because it is a token for full dates using numbers (note that it was neither needed for the elfter example). It is true though that with **November** it does work even with the year expressed using hundreds. But in general, it seems that only expressing the years with thousands, you will get correct transcriptions.

Comment: BTW, even on [Google Traductor](https://translate.google.com/?hl=es&tab=TT) the translation is incorrect when using `neunzehn hundert acht und neunzig` instead of `ein tausend neun hundert acht und neunzig`

Comment: Thanks @Ksign, just ckecked the traductor - brilliant hint, I was not even knowing it :-)

Comment: btw, I have put this issue into https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186559805

Comment: It is still not working as you can test here:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=de&tl=en&text=30019%201986&op=translate

If you say 'dreißigster elfter neunzehn hundert acht und sechzig' -> it still does not work. Nobody from google is paying attention to it - although I am a paying customer :-(