# Google STT - German - Full numeric date not transcribed properly

Tags: date, google-cloud-platform, transcription, google-speech-to-text-api

I am currently experimenting with Google's STT engine for the german language. I am looking to capture full dates from an utterance. This works fine as long as I utter the month as a word (September, October..) *"Erster Januar 1980"* is transcribed correctly.
In german it is common to not say the name of the month, but just the ordinal number of the month like *"Erster Erster Neunzehnhundertachtzig"*, where the first word is the day, the second the month followed by the year. Uttering this, the google engine returns only garbage. I have also tried it with MS Azure and it works fine.

My question is now: Has anyone else stumbled over this, and maybe has a hint how to work around this problem? I have already tried to add a `SpeechContext $FULLDATE` but it does not make a difference.

Cheers
S

Comment: Have you tried to use [boost feature](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation-model#fine-tune_transcription_results_using_boost) ? Does it improve the quality of STT API recognition?

Comment: Yes, but it does not make a difference. It seems the engine is not familiar with that german month as ordinal number concept.

Comment: I found the similar Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799469) unresolved yet. To get better problem diagnosis I suggest to file a support case via Google issue [tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), thus it will increase a chance to revise `de_de` [Class tokens](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens)  by the product developers. Does it sound reasonable for you?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the headsup I will open a support case for this. I also think it is a bug or gap in the de-de STT language model.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022**

A new Dynamic [Class Token](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens) **`$OOV_CLASS_FULLDATE`** has been introduced and it is available for *de-DE*, *de-AT* and *de-CH* language codes.

Comment: I have opened the mentioned thread overhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799469. I got also informed from google developers that the issue was fixed, but I was not able to approve this. I am really curious to learn if somebody managed to improve the results ?